# Y values shift up and down

Tags: c#, charts

I have plotted a graph in c#. How can I move the graph vertically up and down when a button is pressed.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        chart1.Series[0].Points.Clear();
        if (button1.Enabled == true)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
                chart1.Series[0].Points.AddXY(i, Y1scale(i) + 1);
        }

        
    }
```

this is the code I have coded. But only on the first click it works. Further I want to move the graph continuously like in an oscilloscope without jumping from 1 y unit to another

Comment: Can you share more information about `Y1scale`?

Comment: once the values from combo box is selected the amplitude of the wave changes as given in the code                                                                                                
    `private Double Y1scale(double x)

        {

            double a = Convert.ToDouble(comboBox1.SelectedItem);
            
            return 5*(Math.Sin(x))/a;

            
        }` @JerYango

Comment: I am not sure if I understand what you wanted. What do you mean it does not work after the first click? Could it be that the graph changed, but the x/y-axis intervals automatically adjusted giving the impression that it did not change?

Comment: only on the first click graph shift vertically upwards. Even if the button is clicked after that, the graph remain in the same position without shifting vertically upwards. I don't want to change the intervals of x or y graph. Only requirement is to shift the graph vertically at each click @JerYango

Comment: [chart before first click](https://i.imgur.com/gStNlMb.jpeg)

Comment: [after first click](https://i.imgur.com/7mnMXU4.jpg)

Comment: So, the first click raised the graph by 1 unit on the y-axis, and then clicking the button one more time did not update anything in the graph. Is my understanding correct?
It might be because you are clearing the previous data with `chart1.Series[0].Points.Clear();` so the recomputed data is the same with the first click.

Comment: You can either change the y-values ie modify the data. Or you can take control on the y-axis' minimum and maximum range  - Your code obviously doesn't change the data but only creates datapoint form the same data each time.. We don't see what `Y1scale but you would have to either change that or add something else instead of always `1`. Create a counte `yOffset` which you can increment (and decremt) as you like..

Comment: I use  a counter  and each mouse click is counted and y values are shifted adding count value to the existing y value. `private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if(radioButton1.Checked==true)
            {
                ch1_count_up++;
                chart1.Series[0].Points.Clear();
                for (int i = -20; i < 20; i++)
                    chart1.Series[0].Points.AddXY(i, Y1scale(i) + (ch1_count_up / 10) - (ch1_count_down / 10));
            }`

Answer (score 0):

I use  a counter  and each mouse click is counted and y values are shifted adding count value to the existing y value.

```
public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    double ch1_count_up=0;
    double ch1_count_down = 0;
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(radioButton1.Checked==true)
        {
            ch1_count_up++;
            chart1.Series[0].Points.Clear();
            for (int i = -20; i < 20; i++)
                chart1.Series[0].Points.AddXY(i, Y1scale(i) + (ch1_count_up / 10) - (ch1_count_down / 10));
        }
```